# Can a body you fed on as a werewolf still be looted when you're out of werewolf form?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The title, yeah so can you loot bodies that have been fed on?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.

Tip: After all enemies have been defeated you can simply use the wait feature (T key on PC) to wait an hour or two for the werewolf form to wear off.

Comment: Are you sure ? I am never able to use "Wait" feature when i am in werewolf form.

Comment: yes, works for me. you just have to make sure that no enemies are around. This page also says that you can 'wait' in the notes section: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf